# How to relabel some newly calculated columns that were concatenated to an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, rename

I aim to relabel some newly calculated columns that I concatenated to an existing dataframe.

In short I had the following steps:

- a. I pulled a dataframe with 4 stocks from yahoo finance library (a
  235 x 28)
- b. I then calculated log returns (235 x 4) and concatenated
  them
- c. created new labels
- d. how to replace the labels for b's newly
  added columns?

my question is how to perform step d?
(see code below)

```
# Install yfinance and matplotlib package
!pip install yfinance
!pip install matplotlib

# Import yfinance and matplotlib
import yfinance as yf  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# list of interesting stocks, ETFs by ticker
slist = ['SPY', 'AAPL', 'QQQ', 'AMZN']

# step a: Get the data for list of stocks specified by s plus start date, and end date
df = yf.download(slist,'2020-01-01','2020-12-06')
print(df)
print(df.shape)

# step b: concatenate the Log Returns onto the existing df
df = pd.concat([df, np.log(df['Adj Close']/df['Adj Close'].shift(1)).dropna()], axis = 1)
print(df)
print(df.shape)

# one can see that the concatenated columns don't have the appropriate header labels yet
# they just have the name of the tickers in slist
df.head().iloc[ :, -len(slist):]

# step c: create new labels where it becomes ticker + ' Log Rtn' and try to use these
slabel = [s + ' Log Rtn' for s in slist]
print(slabel)

# step d: Here I would like to rename the headers of the part that was added to dataframe, df, such that it uses (slabel)

# show correct end results hopefully
df.head().iloc[ :, -len(slist):]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the new column header's name are from `slist`; then this should work.

```
slist = ['SPY', 'AAPL', 'QQQ', 'AMZN']
for prev_hd, new_hd in zip(slist, slabel):
    df = df.rename(columns={prev_hd: new_hd})
```

## More genrally

```
df = df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})
```